# Why does my regex code skip the first quote?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to filter a username from an xml file. The xml file looks like `<player id="123456" name="somename" alliance="123"/>`. Now I tried the following regex: `preg_match("/name=\"(.*)\"/")`. But somehow although I have put the `\"` behind the star symbol, it seems like my regex does not stop at the first `"` but at the third. This is what I get: `somename" alliance="123`
What is the reason for this?

Comment: Might be better off using an XML parser instead of regex here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, it will match as many characters as it can so it will not stop until just before the very last `"` in your string.  Change it to `.*?` and it should only match until the next `"`, since the `?` makes the repetition lazy instead of greedy.

Take a look at the "Laziness instead of Greediness" section on this [regex reference page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's in the so-called "greedy" mode -- it will match as much as it can.

Use `?` to stop that, like so:

```
/name=\"(.*?)\"/
```

Or simply block it from accepting quotes as part of the name, like so:

```
/name=\"([^\"]*)\"/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text ='<player id="123456" name="somename" alliance="123"/>';
if (preg_match("/name=\"([^\"]*)\"/", $text, $match))
{
    $name = $match[1];
}
```